# Cumulative distribution function of a Poisson distributed random variable

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

> The quantity of lost books in a library can be distributed with a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$. The propability that one book is missing at the end of a year is $p$. After the first year $n$ books are missing. Find a cumulative distribution function!

So I only new, that $\lambda=n\cdot p$ and $F_X(x)=\mathrm{e}^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{x}}{x!}$. How I can compute the right distribution function for this case? Maybe with an approximation of an binomial-distribution?

Have you any hints for me? Thank you!

Comment: A distribution of how many books were lost given that $n$ were lost?

Comment: @GuachoPerez Yes, I think thats the task!

Comment: The question is not clear. `Ascertain a distribution assuming that n books were lost` ...?????

Comment: @wolfies Ah sorry, I think a distribution function!

Comment: @jacmeird  Please rephrase the last sentence of your exercise.

Comment: @callculus So I have to write down a distribution function with probability p. And I know that n books aren't in the library after the first year since the opening of this library. It's clearer now?

Comment: @jacmeird Maybe it´s clearer now. But it doesn´t help me to find an approach.

Comment: @wolfies@GuachoPerez any idea?